# I got error in this line"If objHTML.parseError.ErrorCode <> 0 Then" & the error is 438 object doesn't support property or method

Tags: excel, vba, mshtml

```
Option Explicit

Function CheckHTMLErrors(ByVal htmlString As String) As Long
    ' This function checks if there are any errors in the HTML tags of a given string
    ' and returns the appropriate Excel color code
    
    Dim objHTML As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Set objHTML = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    
    ' Load the HTML string into the HTMLDocument object and check for errors
    objHTML.body.innerHTML = htmlString
    If objHTML.parseError.ErrorCode <> 0 Then
        ' An error occurred during parsing, return red color code (ColorIndex = 3)
        CheckHTMLErrors = 3
    Else
        ' No errors, return no fill color (ColorIndex = 0)
        CheckHTMLErrors = 0
    End If
End Function
```

I'm trying to make a macro to check on the html tags syntax , if it is correct or not.

Comment: HTML parsing is typically very forgiving, owing to years of everyone not perfectly following the "rules" for how HTML should be structured (closing tags omitted etc etc).  I believe that's why the push to "XHTML" never succeeded and why it's going to be difficult to know if your HTML is "correct".

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that an `MSHTML.HTMLDocument` object (which is what `objHTML` is defined as in your code) does not have a `parseError` Property (and, for info, the `parseError` Property does not have an `ErrorCode` Property).

As you have a reference to the MSHTML library in your VBA project, you can see this by (on an empty line) typing `objHTML.` ... as you type the '.' (dot) then the VBE's IntelliSense will list the available members for you.

AFAIK, setting `objHTML.body.innerHTML` to any valid String will never raise a VBA error.